# GraphQL - 'either / or' for multiple required input fields

Tags: python, types, schema, graphql, relay

I'm working on a Relay-compliant GraphQL schema and would like to include a mutation that takes an input object that requires either one argument (the ID of a record) or two other arguments (a record number and a catalog number for the record). I'm using Python and the [Graphene](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene) library. Here's an snippet of the current input object that doesn't allow for the ID to be used instead of the number / catalog:

```
class CreateRecord(relay.ClientIDMutation):
    "The parameters of a newly created record."
    # Relay-compliant mutations need to specify an input class.
    class Input:
        "The available inputs for the CreateRecord mutation."
        part_id = graphene.Int(description='The ID of the record.')
        part_number = graphene.String(description='The record number.',
                                      required=True)
        catalog = graphene.String(description='The catalog of the record.',
                                  required=True)
```

I've looked into interfaces and unions in order to make this happen, but haven't had any luck so far. Without a more flexible input object, I'll likely need to create another mutation (like `CreateRecordUsingID`). Is there a way to achieve this, or more generally to support this functionality in GraphQL schemas?

Comment: I have the same question about queries. For example, when querying for a user, an ID or username should be provided - but not both. I am not sure if this type of validation is supported out of the box. It seems like a common pattern.

Comment: @jfizz See my answer, it applies to your case as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to express conditional non-nullness in the type system. So you'd have to validate this in the resolution logic yourself.

But, why wouldn't you split this into 2 separate explicit operations instead? One that requires an ID and one that requires the record and catalog numbers? Yes, you'll have to name them differently, but explicitness is a good thing and you'll be working with and not against the type system.

There's a good article series on mutation design, and [this entry](https://medium.com/@__xuorig__/graphql-mutation-design-anemic-mutations-dd107ba70496) in particular is pertinent to your case.